# How Do You Store Website Backups?

Tags: security

I'm not that great about backing up my site, which is something I want to improve on.  Currently, I save backups of my site on my local computer and on an external thumb drive.

I was thinking of purchasing some online storage so I could store my website backups there instead.  I'd like to hear about what everyone here does for website backups, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of methods and your approach will depend on the type of website you're running and what your budget looks like.  If you're working on a basic, small static site on your computer and publishing it to a server somewhere, then you already have two copies (local and the remote server) and are probably safe.  You could add a basic service like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) and periodically put a copy in there to push it to another off-site location.

If you're running a more complex site on a dedicated server, then I'd recommend keeping a copy of everything (including database SQL scripts) in a source control system.  Services such as [Unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com/) offer free basic accounts which will give you access to source control and a basic ticketing system, among other things, which not only keeps a copy of the website in its off-site source control repository, but also tracks changes as they're checked in.  You can add to this a service such as [Tomahawk](http://www.tomahawkbackup.com/), which runs on the server, to keep the server's copy of the files and live data backed up regularly and automatically.

For larger deployments with multiple servers, it's likely that you will have someone with more experience available who can provide guidance and the use of on-site backup tools in concert with more robust off-site backup solutions to ensure nothing is ever lost.

Answer (score 0):

I tar.gz my site and upload it to dropbox, thats if its under 2 GB

Calum

Answer (score 0):

I currently use a cronjob that exports everything in MySQL, and then rsyncs that and everything to my local machine in a Dropbox folder and an external hard drive.

Also, since I use Subversion, the main code itself is backed up both on my local machine and on the SVN server.

However, with so many duplicate versions of the code I would be a bit scared about actually restoring a backup, so any ideas as to how to handle that are welcome.